# How to get WCF RIA SupportsCancelation == true

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, ria

Using WCF RIA Service, how can a load operation be cancelled? The SupportsCancelation is readonly and always seems to return false.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.ria.operationbase.supportscancellation%28v=vs.91%29.aspx)

> true if the operation supports
>   cancellation; otherwise, false. This
>   implementation always returns false.

So it always returns false by default unless you have a class that overrides this behavior.

have you tried [LoadOperation.Cancel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.operationbase.cancel%28v=VS.91%29.aspx) anyways ?

```
MyContext ctx = new MyContext();

var loadOp = ctx.Load<Entity>(ctx.GetEntities());
loadOp.Cancel();
```

Comment: i was using that but it didnt seem to work. Seems to be working now though :/